# Difference between jdbc driver and connectors

Tags: mysql-connector, informatica, informatica-powercenter, connector

From what I understand, jdbc drivers provide interface to connect to database,read data,write data. But isn't informatica connectors also about the same thing i.e. connect to database,read data,write data. then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: What are "informatica connectors"? You may need to provide more context for us to even understand your question. JDBC drivers are a Java standard, "informatica connectors", whatever they are, are not a Java standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODBC/JDBC drivers provide basic connectivity and features. Informatica dedicated connectors can take advantege of advanced features, e.g. bulk mode, truncates instead of deletetes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference really is the language that the drivers were written, Java and C, C++ and many other differences like those described in the link below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-odbc-jdbc/